# Jwt token invalid credentials in symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, jwt, postman

I am having a problem in generating jwt token in symfony using this package

lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle . I followed carefully the documentation and have an invalid credentials error ( credentials are correct )

this is my security.yaml

```
security:
   enable_authenticator_manager: true
   # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
   password_hashers:
       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
       App\Entity\User:
           algorithm: auto

   # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
   providers:
       # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
       app_user_provider:
           entity:
               class: App\Entity\User
               property: email
   firewalls:
       login:
           pattern: ^/api/login
           stateless: true
           json_login:
               check_path: /api/login_check # or api_login_check as defined in config/routes.yaml
               success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
               failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
#                username_path: username
#                password_path: password

       api:
           pattern: ^/api
           methods: [POST]
           stateless: true
           guard:
               authenticators:
                   - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

   access_control:
       - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and this is my user entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
#[ApiResource(formats: ["json"])]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    private $email;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private $password;

    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword): void
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
         $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

now when i make the request from post man to get the token it tells me (the route is correct and well defined ) :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid credentials."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the configuration. Just add them back and replace `username_path: username` with  `username_path: email`.

```
json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

Also add in the config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml:

```
user_identity_field: email
```

Comment: I have the same problem but by doing the above I get the same error